# How to edit multiple files with same scriptin/scriptout using vim

Tags: vimscript

When I use a command like `vim -s script *.cfg` it stops at the end of first file stating that there are x files left to edit and not executing the script in the remaining matching files.

`script` contains commands to format files and works when passing single file as argument.

What is the correct format to include all files with similar name and edit with same script file?

Comment: I don't want to open all files simultaneously i want to edit all .cfg files with the script but without entering their names one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Your vim script has to handle the looping through the buffer list. Or maybe you can handle it with `:bufdo`, see `:help :bufdo`.

Simpler:

```sh
for file in *.cfg; do
    vim -s scriptin "$file"
done
```